# how to use AbpTenantConnectionStrings

Tags: abp

My requirement is to add multiple connectionstrings based on the tenantId. I have added data in the AbpTenantConnectionStrings.

I found that there is another way to add multi tenant connection string in the below link

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/3.0/Multi-Tenancy

But I don't know exactly how to proceed.

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            Configure<AbpDefaultTenantStoreOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Tenants = new[]
                {
                    new TenantConfiguration(
                        Guid.Parse("446a5211-3d72-4339-9adc-845151f8ada0"), //Id
                        "tenant1" //Name
                    ),
                    new TenantConfiguration(
                        Guid.Parse("25388015-ef1c-4355-9c18-f6b6ddbaf89d"), //Id
                        "tenant2" //Name
                    )
                    {
                        //tenant2 has a seperated database
                        ConnectionStrings =
                        {
                            {ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnectionStringName, "..."}
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
        }
```